# Remove all formatting, numbered lists, bullet lists, spaces, tabs, etc from a string

Tags: java, formatting, jtextarea

I'm making a custom document compare tool. I am comparing the content from a word document to a webpages content. I am parsing the webpage and just removing the text and comparing it to text I am copying from a word document into a JTextarea.

All I want to do is compare the text, make sure that there are no spelling mistakes or missing words. When I parse the webpage I don't get any formatting like numbered or bulleted lists. My problem is, is when I copy the contents of my word doc to my jtextarea it preserves all the numbered lists, bulleted lists etc.

What I want is to take to following text example:

> Solution 1: Restart your network hardware
>
> If Xbox LIVE performance seems slow, try restarting your network hardware. Here’s how:
>
> 1. Turn off your Xbox 360 console and any network hardware (for example, your modem and router).
> 2. Wait 30 seconds.
> 3. Turn on your modem, and wait one minute.

And turn it into:

> Solution 1: Restart your network hardware
>   If Xbox LIVE performance seems slow, try restarting your network hardware. Here’s how:
>   Turn off your Xbox 360 console and any network hardware (for example, your modem and router).
>   Wait 30 seconds.
>   Turn on your modem, and wait one minute.

I already have a regex to remove all the blank lines, I just don't know how I should handle removing the extra tabs, list styles etc. Has anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following heuristics:

- replace all Tabs (etc.) with space (see [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))
- replace all spaces-followed-by-number-followed-by-dot-at-the-begining-of-line with space (see regex: `|^ *\d*\\.|` -- carret-space-star-backslash-d-backslash-backslash-dot)
- replace all series-of-spaces (regex: `|  +|` -- space-spaces-plus) with one space (to remove excess) -- keep this as the last step

you can add any other replacement logic there if you encounter other patterns you don't want

*Note*: I added `|` around the regular expressions to make the leading spaces easier to see, but they are not part of the regex when you enter the code.